# What is the best way to center list items using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem how can I fix it?

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9ex0h6knsisc4d/99.JPG?dl=0]

This is the HTML code:

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hyper Design</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>


        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Comment: show your code as well

Comment: I don't kwon, what's your problem. Please, post your code here, your problem, not just an image!

Comment: I'm pretty sure what your problem is, but without seeing your code, there's nothing we can do. Help us to help you by documenting your issue as extensively as possible

Comment: Please don't rely on third party links on Stack Overflow. This is a site that is designed not just to help you but also the thousands of other people searching the Internet for a similar problem. If all you post is a link to your dropbox folder that you're probably going to delete later, that doesn't help others. See [ask] for details.

Comment: @jmort253 I tried to upload the photo in the site but it needs a higher reputation , that's why I uploaded it on dropbox

Comment: @MohamedSobhy - I added the image, but you should still describe the problem you want to solve. First, it might not be obvious to everyone what that problem is, and second, writing a good question is your way of giving back. Most of us here posting answers are also here to learn too, so clearly written questions are things we find really valuable. Even though you got an answer, you can still edit the question to clarify so that it remains a valuable artifact. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Simply use `text-center` class in the collapse tag

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1042/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<center>item1</center><br />

<div id="field">content of item 2</div>

<style>
#field {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e92hek0e/1/

Comment: Please do not use <center>.  It has been depreciated.  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/html_401/html4-ref/article.php/3460291

Answer (score 0):

Adding `text-align:center;` in your CSS should do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/1y2s4v6y/

HOWEVER, my answer is based completely upon assumption as you have not provided any code examples for us to look at.

Comment: After seeing your code, it looks like I am right.  Here is an updated jsfiddle.  text-align:center; is all you need.  http://jsfiddle.net/72gv0cm3/